# What is the best way to get the most YouTube video information like buffer time, video quality and so on?

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api, youtube-data-api

I am an Android developer and I tried to get the YouTube video information like buffer time and video quality by implementing the YouTube fragment. but YouTube Player fragment can just give very limited information. I wanna more, the more the better.
I will try iframe to see if I can get more information. Anyone could give me some advise other than iframe? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So far, what Youtube Data API can give you is the [videos resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource-representation) which contains the properties available for Youtube videos.